# Beginner Question: Idiomatic way to quote non-latin text?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode

I am a hobbyist and very much a beginner at LaTeX. I am typesetting a book and would like to include a quote written in Devanagari script. Here is what I came up with:

```
\newfontfamily\devanagari{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]
{\devanagari
करनियम् अत्थकुसलेन \\
यन् तम् सन्तम् पदम् अभिसमेच्च \\
सक्को उजु च सुजु च \\
सुवचो च्'अस्स मुदु अनतिमनि
}
```

I don't just want to get the job done, I also want to get better at using LaTeX. I would love some feedback on whether this is an idiomatic way to handle this, or if there is a better approach. Thank you!

Comment: Looks good to me. Is there just the one quote or many? Just the one language or several? But maybe someone else will have more to add.

Comment: There will be 10 blocks like this spread through the text, so my thought is to basically do the same thing over and over (minus the \newfontfamily part)

Comment: Sorry, and no additional languages, just this and the English text.

Comment: As you said, just do the same thing over but no need to keep doing `\newfontfamily`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `babel` to set up language switching:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{noto}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
  \babelprovide[import=sa-Deva, hyphenrules=sanskrit]{sanskrit-devanagari}
  \babelfont[*devanagari]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz, Script=Devanagari]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\begin{document}

English


\begin{otherlanguage}{sanskrit-devanagari}
    करनियम् अत्थकुसलेन \\
    यन् तम् सन्तम् पदम् अभिसमेच्च \\
    सक्को उजु च सुजु च \\
    सुवचो च्'अस्स मुदु अनतिमनि
\end{otherlanguage}


Bla bla.

\end{document}
```

[image]
Since Harfbuzz is used, you need to compile with LuaLaTeX

Comment: XeLaTeX should ignore `Renderer=HarfBuzz` with a harmless warning. I haven’t tried it, but other documents like this compiled fine for me in XeLaTeX.